# sql statement with union and order by

Tags: mysql, sql

This SQL is working great, but once I wanted to order my selects using `ORDER BY id` it won't work. All these tables have an `id` type `int`.

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT r1, r2, r3, r4
    FROM table1
        WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%' AND status = 1 LIMIT 0,20 
    UNION
        SELECT   r1, r2, r3, r4  FROM table2
            WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%' AND status = 1 LIMIT 0,20 
    UNION
        SELECT   r1, r2, r3, r4  FROM table3
            WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%' AND status = 1 LIMIT 0,20 
    UNION
        SELECT   r1, r2, r3, r4  FROM table4
            WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%'  AND status = 1 LIMIT 0,20 ");

$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: if you want to order the unioned on id you should keep the id in the union

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Have to include `ID` on each select to keep the struct equal.
- Then put all that between parethesis and assign an alias if need. `( a union b union c ) as ALIAS`
- Last do the `select` on the alias table `SELECT * FROM ALIAS ORDER BY ID`

.

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare(" SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT   id, r1, r2, r3, r4  FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%' AND status = 1 LIMIT 0,20 
     UNION
     SELECT   id, r1, r2, r3, r4  FROM table2 WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%' AND status = 1 LIMIT 0,20 
     UNION
     SELECT   id, r1, r2, r3, r4  FROM table3 WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%' AND status = 1 LIMIT 0,20 
     UNION
     SELECT   id, r1, r2, r3, r4  FROM table4 WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%'  AND status = 1 LIMIT 0,20 
) as Alias ORDER BY ID");
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Maybe few words of explanation?

Comment: @ElonThan Yes, I was still writting, sorry :)

Comment: Heh, send code ASAP to be first and then add everything else. So common ;)

Comment: @ElonThan With Gordon lurking you need to be really fast .

Answer (score 0):

To use `order by` in the the components of a `union`, you need to enclose the subqueries in parentheses.  Then you can include `order by` at the end.  So, this structure will work:

```
(SELECT id, r1, r2, r3, r4 FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%' AND status = 1 LIMIT 0, 20
) UNION
(SELECT id, r1, r2, r3, r4  FROM table2 WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%' AND status = 1 LIMIT 0, 20 
) UNION
(SELECT id, r1, r2, r3, r4  FROM table3 WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%' AND status = 1 LIMIT 0, 20 
) UNION
(SELECT id, r1, r2, r3, r4  FROM table4 WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%'  AND status = 1 LIMIT 0, 20)
ORDER BY id;
```

Note:  With this structure, you need to include the `id` in the column list if you want to order by it.